# Connect two external screens to notebook

Tags: multiple-monitors

I need to connect two external screens to my notebook. I know this has been discussed a couple of times before but although I did some research I am still not sure what my best option is. 
My graphic card is a GeForce GT 750M. My notebook as only one HDMI output and some USB outputs. 
One external screen I have already in use via the HDMI output. So, what would be my best option if I want to...

1. ...connect an old screen which only supports VGA
2. ...buy a new screen/adapter or whatever it takes to have two external screens supported?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What brand and model of laptop? What research have you done to resolve this on your own?

Comment: Hi, I have a Dell Inspiron 7537. I checked other threads on this fourm as well on different forums but in most cases an aditional VGA output is presumed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to connect a USB-to-VGA adapter on your USB ports. Once properly configured, the OS (that, actually, should be explicitely supported by the adapter manufacturer) will recognize the adapter as an additional external video card, giving you the possibility to extend/clone your desktop. As an example, a 10 seconds search on the web led me to [this one](http://www.startech.com/m/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-VGA-Adapter-External-Video-Card-PC-Mac~USB2VGAPRO2) (that, btw, supports up to 4 distinct adapters to be used concurrently, for a total of 5 display).